# Trim twice or trim and assign to a variable which will be more faster in perfomance, javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a email validation fuction where i need to trim string value twice.

```
(val) => (val.trim() && emailReg.test(val.trim()))
```

Or

```
(val) => { 
   const value = val.trim();
     return value &&emailReg.test(value) 
}
```

which is more faster and meet coding standards.

Comment: Second one is faster.

Comment: Why are you bothering with the `&&` part? Doesn’t your `emailReg` reject the empty string? `(val) => emailReg.test(val.trim())`

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on personal preference, so either one is fine (as long as they both work).

However, the most performant option is the **second option**.

This is because you are only trimming the string *once*, which will save a few milliseconds when returning the value.

```js
const emailReg = undefined; // Email RegEx

const emailTest = (val) => {
  const value = val.trim(); // Only trimming once
  return value && emailReg.test(value) // Passing both of the variables
}
```

*Edit: However, it may take a few milliseconds when making a new memory reference for the variable.*

Again, choose whichever you like (mainly depends on personal preference).

Comment: But the secknd optiln will create a new memory reference right?. And there must be some milliseconds required for it

Comment: Yes, but like I said in the answer, it all comes down to personal preference.